# Powershell in MsBuild: Check if script succeeded?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I am using a powershell script to perform a few tasks that are pre requisites for my MsBuild. The script is called from the build itself. How do i check if the script succeeded so that my build can continue, else fail.

Comment: Do you mean you use `<Exec Command="powershell..."` in msbuild? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to return a non exit zero code from your script that would indicate that the build failed. So something like this at the end of the script:

```
if ($error) { exit 1 }
```

that would exit with a code of 1 if any errors occured during the script